# Flash issues on Windows

Tags: flash, apache-flex, cross-browser, flex4.5

I have a website [here](http://queirozf.com) and you'll see that I have a little **Flex 4.5** app I made to display some images (book covers).

This app runs fine on **Chrome** (as always) but sometimes chokes for people accessing my site from **IE** and **FF** running on a windows platform..

The 'choke' in question is :

**--** either not displaying anything at all, (not even the customary adobe logo prompting users to download the newest flash plugin) just a black screen, no progress bars or anything.

**--** taking too long on the 'second' progress bar.

**--** sometimes, after a few refreshes, a 2046 error comes up too. (on linux too)

I'd like to know whether any of you has run into this and if there are any fixes.

Thanks.

**P.S.**: I'm aware that this post looks like self-advertising but I think that the link to my website is relevant here.

**P.S.2**: Once more I'm delighted with Chrome and disappointed in the other browsers.. **Why doesn't Adobe create their own browser??** It would solve half the world's problems..

Comment: Why would Adobe create their own browser?  There's no business purpose of it and Adobe supports Google the best.  Plus, the last thing we need is another browser to piss off developers.

Comment: Strange comment to add -- I had it freeze in a loading bar, but when I clicked on it a few times it finished loading (FF 5.0)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd like to question as to *why* you're using Flex for such a tiny piece of information.  You'd be better off creating a pure Actionscript project since Flex is overkill for this and would take longer to load.  Flex is made for RIA; this is not an RIA.

Second, have you tried to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) which is part of the Flash Builder release process (or you can do it manually)? The `object` tag in HTML isn't consistent across all browsers (especially IE) and SWFObject removes that incompatibility.

As for your other issues, I would imagine it's a problem with your code and 'timing'.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not even sure I know what a 'pure Actionscript' is or what I can do with it... I'll look into into though....

Comment: Hmm I'll look into this SWFObject thing. Is it a custom HTML tag? We can use it in the same way we would an '<object>' ??

Comment: It's javascript.  It's better and simpler to use.